# No module named 'xmltodict'

Tags: python, xml, anaconda3, xmltodict

I'm trying to convert an XML to JSON using 'xmltodict'

My code:

```
import xmltodict
import json
with open('ELT.xml') as inFh:
    with open('ELT.json','w') as outFh:
        json.dump(xmltodict.parse(inFh.read()), outFh)
```

The error:

```
 import xmltodict
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmltodict'
```

I tried: pip install xmltodict but got this result:

```
C:\Users\user>pip install xmltodict
Requirement already satisfied: xmltodict in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.12.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is sometimes caused by pip version. 
Please upgrade pip to latest version and then uninstall and reinstall the xmltodict package.

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed pip. Then I tried reinstall xmltodict, but I get the same error. I checked the version history of xmltodict and it's the most up-to-date version.

Comment: In your virtual environment you will find python.exe and pip.exe try to run pip from the virtual environment and install it and see if it fixes